# IF statement with OR and NOT operators does not work as expected

Tags: if-statement, logic, compare

```
<?php

$param = 'c';

if ($param != 'a' || $param != 'b') 
{
    echo 'Param != a OR b';
}else
{
    echo 'Param = a OR b';
}

?>
```

The `if` statement above does not work as expected because the `if` will ALWAYS evaluate to TRUE regardless of the value of `$param`.

Is there another way to construct the `if` statement that will work as expected (keeping the original intention... i.e. `$param` not being equal to `a` or `b`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
!(A OR B) = !A AND !B
!(A AND B) = !A OR !B
```

In your case, you have to replace the `||` with the `&&` operator.

Comment: So, in your case, changing the "||" to "&&" will fix your code.

Comment: De Morgan's law at its simplest!
 
Thanks. I used the NOT (!) before, but I guess I left out the brackets. Anyway, your answer was spot on!